# Accessing Data from Javascript API call

Tags: javascript, python, api, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to access the data shown on this website: [Link](http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/obligationer/danmark)
using either python requests or requests-html.
The site calls this API: [API](http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/webproxy/DataFeedProxy.aspx)

I've tried copying the POST request using Insomnia (Copying cURL). I get a response code 200 but an error saying "Error getting base data: Error parsing xmlsquery"

How can i get this data into a pandas dataframe? i would like to avoid using Selenium.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi kabk, welcome to StackOverflow. the link you copied as API is not an actual API which can be queried. I think you're stuck with using selenium and scraping the data or looking for an (open) API to access that data.

Comment: maybe first show your code so we could see what is wrong in your method.

Comment: Thank you. My experience with webscraping and api's is quite limited. I will stick with selenium then.

Comment: OK, but I resolved this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you used to send request
but when I use module `requests` then problem makes `+` in query.

`requests` converts `+` to `%2B` but server needs `+`.

It needs to manually convert data using `urllib.parse` with `safe="+"`

```
data = {
    "xmlquery": "<post>\n<param+name=\"Exchange\"+value=\"NMF\"/>\n<param+name=\"SubSystem\"+value=\"Prices\"/>\n<param+name=\"Action\"+value=\"GetMarket\"/>\n<param+name=\"inst__a\"+value=\"0,1,2,5,21,23\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt\"+value=\"/nordicV3/paging_inst_table.xsl\"/>\n<param+name=\"Market\"+value=\"GITS:CO:CPHCB,GITS:CO:CPHBB,M:GITS:CO:CPHTA,GITS:CO:CPHAU,GITS:CO:CPHSA\"/>\n<param+name=\"RecursiveMarketElement\"+value=\"True\"/>\n<param+name=\"XPath\"+value=\"//inst[@itid='2'+or+@itid='3']\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_lang\"+value=\"en\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_tableId\"+value=\"bondsSearchDKTable\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_options\"+value=\",noflag,\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_hiddenattrs\"+value=\",fnm,isrid,dlt,tp,bb,ib,cpt,rps,os,lt,st,itid,lists,it,mkt,\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_notlabel\"+value=\",fnm\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_jspcbk\"+value=\"doPaging\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_jsscbk\"+value=\"doSortPager\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_sorder\"+value=\"descending\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_sattr\"+value=\"chp\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_start\"+value=\"0\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_size\"+value=\"100\"/>\n<param+name=\"inst__an\"+value=\"id,nm,fnm,isin,cpnrt,bp,ap,lsp,chp,atap,ed,dlt,cr,isrid,tp,bb,ib,cpt,rps,os,lt,st,itid,lists,it,mkt\"/>\n<param+name=\"app\"+value=\"/obligationer/danmark\"/>\n</post>"
}

data_str = urllib.parse.urlencode(data, safe="+")
```

---

Full working code:

In code you can see all needed headers to access server.

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

data = {
    "xmlquery": "<post>\n<param+name=\"Exchange\"+value=\"NMF\"/>\n<param+name=\"SubSystem\"+value=\"Prices\"/>\n<param+name=\"Action\"+value=\"GetMarket\"/>\n<param+name=\"inst__a\"+value=\"0,1,2,5,21,23\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt\"+value=\"/nordicV3/paging_inst_table.xsl\"/>\n<param+name=\"Market\"+value=\"GITS:CO:CPHCB,GITS:CO:CPHBB,M:GITS:CO:CPHTA,GITS:CO:CPHAU,GITS:CO:CPHSA\"/>\n<param+name=\"RecursiveMarketElement\"+value=\"True\"/>\n<param+name=\"XPath\"+value=\"//inst[@itid='2'+or+@itid='3']\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_lang\"+value=\"en\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_tableId\"+value=\"bondsSearchDKTable\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_options\"+value=\",noflag,\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_hiddenattrs\"+value=\",fnm,isrid,dlt,tp,bb,ib,cpt,rps,os,lt,st,itid,lists,it,mkt,\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_notlabel\"+value=\",fnm\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_jspcbk\"+value=\"doPaging\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_jsscbk\"+value=\"doSortPager\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_sorder\"+value=\"descending\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_sattr\"+value=\"chp\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_start\"+value=\"0\"/>\n<param+name=\"ext_xslt_size\"+value=\"100\"/>\n<param+name=\"inst__an\"+value=\"id,nm,fnm,isin,cpnrt,bp,ap,lsp,chp,atap,ed,dlt,cr,isrid,tp,bb,ib,cpt,rps,os,lt,st,itid,lists,it,mkt\"/>\n<param+name=\"app\"+value=\"/obligationer/danmark\"/>\n</post>"
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0', 
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',    
}

url = 'http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/webproxy/DataFeedProxy.aspx'

data_str = urllib.parse.urlencode(data, safe="+")

response = requests.post(url, data=data_str, headers=headers)

#print(response.text)

import pandas as pd

all_tables = pd.read_html(response.text)
df = all_tables[1]

print(df)
```

---

How I found `+`:

Python code was giving `"Error getting base data: Error parsing xmlsquery"` - so problem was in `xmlsquery`.

I copied working xmlsquery from request in browser using `DevTool` (tab: `Network`) in `Chrome`/`Firefox`
and compared (char-by-char) with `response.request.body` from Python code.

```
correct = "xmlquery=...from browser..."
wrong   = response.request.body

for char_a, char_b in zip(correct, wrong):
    if char_a != char_b:
       print(char_a, char_b)
```